# Why aren’t posit arithmetic representations commonly used?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, hardware, posit-number-system

I recently found [this library](https://github.com/stillwater-sc/universal) that seems to provide its own types and operations on real numbers that are 2 to 3 orders of magnitude faster than normal floating point arithmetic.

The library is based on using a different representation for real numbers. One that is described to be both more efficient and mathematically accurate than floating point - posit.

If this representation is so efficient why isn’t it widely used in all sorts of applications and implemented in hardware, or maybe it is? As far as I know most typical hardware uses some kind of IEEE floating point representation for real numbers.

Is it somehow maybe only applicable to some very specific AI research, as they seem to list mostly that as an example?

If this representation is not only hundreds to thousands of times faster than floating point, but also much more deterministic and designed for use in concurrent systems, why isn’t it implemented in GPUs, which are basically massively concurrent calculators working on real numbers? Wouldn’t it bring huge advances in rendering performance and GPU computation capabilities?

Update: People behind the linked [Universal](https://github.com/stillwater-sc/universal) library have released a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.11011) about their design and implementation.

Comment: IEEE is omnipresent. If someone comes up with more efficient implementation, it will take **a lot** of time to switch. Some softwares rely on IEEE representation and likely will never be able to switch to the new one. Nonetheless, I did not do enough research regarding the library you linked so I cannot provide any meaningful comments on it.

Comment: " 2 to 3 orders of magnitude faster than normal floating point arithmetic." --> Somethings has to give, precision, range, correctness, compactness.  The most likely reason for non acceptance is that if true by 2 or 3 orders, it is so for _select_  problems.

Comment: "If this representation is not only hundreds to thousands of times faster than floating point". Can you give a reference for this statement?

Comment: @geza It’s from the linked page. At the beginning of the readme they say that in some applications it is possible to achieve a speed up of 2 to 3 orders of magnitude. Later they give an example: “Both Google and Microsoft have jettisonned IEEE floating point for their AI cloud services to gain two orders of magnitude better performance.”

Comment: Thanks. I think this statement is seldom true. Maybe there are applications where this speedup is achievable (but, to be honest I suspect an unfair comparison here), but I don't think that the operations themselves are (much) faster for posits than floating point. I rather suppose that some algorithms need much less operations if implemented with posits. The reason I think this is that floating point operations are already very fast (usually just several cpu clocks), it's simply impossible to speed them up by 1000x.

Comment: A common FP optimization is to relax the goal of calculating the best answer to `*,/,+,-` from within 0.5 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) to maybe many ULP  for edge conditions.  Yes the result is found faster when more error is tolerable.

Comment: @geza I am not sure how are they supposed to achieve these kinds of speed ups, but I don’t think it is through using a different algorithm, as they describe posits as a “drop in replacement for IEEE floats”, which implies that the amount and types of operations performed are the same, and it is the speed of the operations that is the only variable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The thing is that this new representation is supposed to be superior in both performance and correctness to floating point. It’s supposed to be more accurate. They also say that IEEE floats were already considered inefficient and inaccurate in the nineties.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: After a brief spin through wikipedia, it appears they've sacrificed precision and range, and focused on compactness. For code that's cache/memory I/O bound, such as machine learning, I can see how that would result in massive performance improvements.  Wikipedia mentions that for general polynomials, posits are slower on average. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)#Type_III_Unum_%E2%80%93_Posit

Comment: @MooingDuck This must be it. After all most applications nowadays are memory bound and most systems are heavily NUMA.

Comment: @MooingDuck: if that's the case, and (for example) they're comparing cases where one case (posit) fit's into the cache, and the other one doesn't (floating point), then I think that's an unfair comparison.

Comment: @geza: If they come up with the same end result, then it's totally a fair comparison. Posit sacrificed precision and range for compactness. If the code doesn't _need_ that precision or range, then all that matters is the compactness, where posit wins.  A better counterargument would be that this (ML) example is cherry-picked. Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Are you asking why no (or hardly any?) hardware exists for a standard which was developed a few years ago, for which barely any software exists? In contrast to a standard which was established decades ago with a lot of legacy software? Also, IMO, the question of (dis-) advantages of either standard is very problem specific and rather opinion-based (not all computations are machine learning ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most objective and convincing reason I know of is that [posits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)#Type_III_Unum_%E2%80%93_Posit) were introduced less than 4 years ago. That's not enough time to make inroads in the marketplace (people need time to develop implementations), much less take it over (which, among other things, requires overcoming incompatibilities with existing software).

Whether or not the industry wants to make such a change is a separate issue that tends towards subjectivity.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the *IEEE standard* seems to be slower is because the *IEEE* addresses some topics with an higher importance. For example:

.
.
.

The *IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)* defines:

*arithmetic formats*: sets of binary and decimal floating-point data, which consist of finite numbers (including signed zeros and subnormal numbers), infinities, and special "not a number" values (NaNs)

*interchange formats*: encodings (bit strings) that may be used to exchange floating-point data in an efficient and compact form

*rounding rules*: properties to be satisfied when rounding numbers during arithmetic and conversions

*operations*: arithmetic and other operations (such as trigonometric functions) on arithmetic formats

*exception handling*: indications of exceptional conditions (such as division by zero, overflow, etc.)

The above is from Wikipedia copied: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

.
.
.

Your linked library, which seems to be called the *posit number system* advocates the following strengths.

*Economical* - No bit patterns are redundant. There is one representation for infinity denoted as ± inf and zero. All other bit patterns are valid distinct non-zero real numbers. ± inf serves as a replacement for NaN.

*Mathematical Elegant* - There is only one representation for zero, and the encoding is symmetric around 1.0. Associative and distributive laws are supported through deferred rounding via the quire, enabling reproducible linear algebra algorithms in any concurrency environment.

*Tapered Accuracy* - Tapered accuracy is when values with small exponent have more digits of accuracy and values with large exponents have fewer digits of accuracy. This concept was first introduced by Morris (1971) in his paper ”Tapered Floating Point: A New Floating-Point Representation”.

*Parameterized precision and dynamic range* -- posits are defined by a size, nbits, and the number of exponent bits, es. This enables system designers the freedom to pick the right precision and dynamic range required for the application. For example, for AI applications we may pick 5 or 6 bit posits without any exponent bits to improve performance. For embedded DSP applications, such as 5G base stations, we may select a 16 bit posit with 1 exponent bit to improve performance per Watt.

*Simpler Circuitry* - There are only two special cases, Not a Real and Zero. No denormalized numbers, overflow, or underflow.

The above is from GitHub copied: https://github.com/stillwater-sc/universal

.
.
.

So, in my opinion, the *posit number system* prefers performance, while the *IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)* prefers technical compatibility and interchangeability.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly challenge the claim of that library being faster than IEEE floating point:

Modern hardware includes circuitry specifically designed to handle IEEE floating point arithmetic. Depending on your CPU model, it can perform roughly 0.5 to 4 floating point operations **per clock cycle**. Yes, this circuitry does complex things, but because it's built in hardware and aggressively optimized for many years, it achieves this kind of speed.

**Any software library that provide a different floating point format must perform the arithmetic in software**. It cannot just say "please multiply these two numbers using double precision arithmetic" and see the result appear in the corresponding register two clock cycles later, it must contain code that takes the four different parts of the posit format, handles them separately, and fuses together a result. And that code takes time to execute. Much more time than just two clock cycles.

The "universal" library may have corner cases where its posit number format shines. But speed is not where it can hope to compete.

Comment: You are wrong.

_**"Any software library that provide a different floating point format must perform the arithmetic in software."**_: That's exactly what the IEEE standard does. If you don't believe me, buy a working PC with a 386SX CPU without Co-Processor and try to calculate a floating point number. The _IEEE standard_ guarantees a minimum of precision, a maximum of compatibility, at cost of performance, while the _posit number system_ guarantees the maximum amount of precision and maximum amount of performace your hardware is able to do, at costs of compatibility.

Comment: @paladin When did you buy your last PC? In the last milenium? I have not seen a CPU without floating point support since the nineties. And the CPUs that are still built without floating point support (embedded processors), they do not run software with any substantial amount of floating point arithmetic. Because if they did, the cheapest thing to do would be to include an FPU, not to use a different floating point format.

Comment: My point was that IEEE is also from the last millennium. Make yourself a joy and program a program which calculates PI and watch what problems might occur.

Comment: @paladin Well, the universal library is not from the last millennium. So, when I judge its performance, I will use modern hardware as the reference, not hardware from the stone age of computing.

Comment: Compatibility layers produce a lot of overhead and thus reducing the theoretical maximal performance. And the IEEE standard has for sure a lot of compatibility layers. The _posit number system_ is also faster on newer hardware, that's why those guys (Microsoft, Google, Amazon, etc.) use it in the first place. Please do yourself a favour and read about how this library actually works.

Comment: @paladin Well, I did a bit of reading. And I asked myself, what needs to happen when you add posit numbers: 1) You must decode their regimes, which is nontrivial to do as this is a unary coding. Assembler tricks can give you constant time decoding, but you are including at least one conditional instruction. 2) You must decode the exponent and mantissa fields based on the regime. 3) You must adjust the exponents. 4) You must add the mantissas. 5) You must repack the fields into a posit number. All that in software. I acknowledge the small coded size, but certainly no arithmetic speed advantage.

Comment: This may be true, but in practice, nobody is simply adding floating point numbers. Those numbers will, in 99% of all cases, be multiplied, and in those cases, the posit system is much faster and much more precise. That's why, I was suggesting to you to program a program which calculates PI, or any other non trivial number, to see the advantages.

Comment: @paladin My old laptop can execute a complete loop iteration with a double precision multiplication in exactly 5 CPU cycles. You simply don't beat that with posit numbers. No way.

Comment: Tell me how many CPU cycles your old laptop needs to do a simple (most probably integer) addition. That's what you need for multiplying (e^x)(e^y). Tell me how many CPU cycles your old laptop need to do a simple (most probably integer) multiplication. That's what you need for multiplying (x^e)(y^e). Now tell me how calculating with post numbers may be slower than calculating with IEEE.

Comment: @paladin Tell me, how many cycles your CPU needs for counting leading zeros. Tell me, how many cycles it needs for checking the sign bit and negating the rest of the posit number to even be able to count the bits. Tell me, how many cycles it needs to mask out the regime from the number. How many cycles it needs to split the remaining bits into exponent and mantissa bits. How many cycles to update the exponent in case the multiplication overflowed, how many to create a new regime, how many to join exponent and mantissa, etc. pp.

Comment: I would imagine the decode of a posit would be done in one clock cycle if implemented in hardware.  But in software the fundamental operations cannot be faster.  In hardware, it's a bit more expensive than IEEE in terms of area.  Not sure industry will bother after going so strong on IEEE for so long.  By the way FPUs are no longer used, modern compilers on modern processors use SSE instructions

Comment: @GregoryMorse There are current CPU designs with/without floating point support, with/without integer vector support, and with/without floating point vector support. It's true that FPUs have been included into the CPU chip since the last milenium, and thus that the distinction between fixed/floating point units has become less clear. (The integer ALUs and floating point ALUs remain two very different beasts, though.) As such, feel free to interpret "include an FPU" as "include instructions that perform floating point arithmetic".